# Открытие закрытого приложения

Tags: java, android

Как осуществить вызов окна закрытого приложения на Андроид? Хотя бы диалогового. Раньше делал так, но в Андроид 10-... такая штука не работает.
Был Foreground Service и из ресивера вызывал context.startActivity(int9);
А как это делают всякие приложения типа Ватс Апа, ВК, которые выводят свои звонки на заблокированный экран телефона?
П.С. У меня не какое-то плохое приложение, а полезное.